# Using ggplot to plot regresion coefficients

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am tring to plot a coef. estimates for multiple model using ggplot.

I want wo estima a few model and then plot theirs points estimates at the same time into one plot.

Using simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)

model1 = lm(hp ~ gear + am + mpg + carb, data = mtcars)
model2 = lm(hp ~ gear + am  + I(am^2) + mpg + carb, data = mtcars)
model3 = lm(hp ~ gear + am  + I(am^2) + mpg + carb, data = mtcars)
model4 = lm(hp ~ gear + am  + I(am^2) + mpg , data = mtcars)
model5 = lm(hp ~ gear + am  + I(am^2) + log(mpg) + log(carb), data = mtcars)



ce = function(model.obj) {
  extract = summary(get(model.obj))$coefficients[ ,1:2]
  return(data.frame(extract, vars=row.names(extract), model=model.obj))
}

# Run function on the three models and bind into single data frame
coefs = do.call(rbind, sapply(paste0(list("model1", "model2", "model3", "model4", "model5")), ce, simplify=FALSE))

names(coefs)[2] = "se" 


ggplot(coefs, aes(vars, Estimate)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, lty=2, lwd=1, colour="red") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Estimate - se, ymax=Estimate + se, colour=vars), 
                lwd=1, width=0) +
  geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=vars)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ model) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  labs(x="Coefficient", y="Value")
```

We will get 5 plots (1 row and 5 columns) is there a simple way how to transform the plots So we will have still 5 plots at the same time but dimension would be 5 rows and 1 columns?

Comment: Just swap the terms in the `facet_grid` - `facet_grid(model ~ .)`

Comment: You could probably have a look at the `ggarrange()` function of the `ggpubr` package. It makes it very easy to arrange multiple plots, choosing row/column numbers.

Comment: Thank you very muth both - using realy basic `facet_grid(model ~ .)` I was not aware of this argument